# Why index self instead of instance variable in bracket method

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
class Thing
  def initialize
    @array = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
  end
end

thing = Thing.new
```

The normal way to access an element in `@array` is to use `[]` as in:

```
@array[0][1] # => 0
```

I am trying to overwrite `[]` so as to get results like this:

```
position_array = [0, 1]
@array[position_array] # => 0
```

This is my attempt:

```
class Thing
  def [](position_array)
    index_row, index_col = position_array
    @array[index_row][index_col]
  end

  def get_value(position_array)
    @array[position_array]           # doesn't work
    # self[position_array]           # does work
  end
end

thing.get_value([0, 1])
# >> 'get_value': no implicit conversion of Array into Integer (TypeError)
```

Why do I need to index the `Thing` object in order to index `@array`?

Comment: You might also be interested in [`Array#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-dig), which does something similar to how you want to use `get_value`: `@array.dig(0, 1) # => 0`, `@array.dig(0) # => [0, 0, 0]`; though if you have an array you need to decompose it: `@array.dig(*position_array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think of *message* and *receiver*.

`@array[position_array]` sends the message `[]` to the receiver `@array`. `@array` is an instance of `Array`, so the method [`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) gets invoked.

`self[position_array]` sends the message `[]` to the receiver `self`. Within instance methods, `self` refers to that instance. And because `self` is an instance of `Thing`, the method `Thing#[]` gets invoked.

Since `Thing` is a subclass of `Object` and not a subclass of `Array` (nothing wrong here, you shouldn't subclass `Array` anyway), your implementation of `[]` does *not* override `Array#[]`. Both methods are totally independent of each other, just like `String#[]` or `Hash#[]`.

This is how I would approach it:

```
class Thing
  def initialize
    @array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
  end

  def [](i, j)
    @array[i][j]
  end
end

thing = Thing.new
thing[0, 1] #=> 2
thing[1, 1] #=> 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use a prepended method to non-invasively override the [] method in Array by duck-typing the parameter passed to the [] method, and then calling the original if its not what you expect.  Then you don't need a `Thing` object at all.

```
module MyArrayExtension
  def [] (*param)
    if param.size == 2
      row, col = param
      raise ArgumentError, 'Row must be an integer' if row.class != Integer
      raise ArgumentError, 'Column must be an integer' if col.class != Integer
      raise ArgumentError, "Element at row #{row} is not an array" if self[row].class != Array
      self[row][col]
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

class Array
  prepend MyArrayExtension
end

thing = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
puts "The 2D array is: #{thing}"
puts "Extension used on the thing to get at element 1 of first array:"
puts thing[0,1]

puts '-' * 20

normal = [1,2,:blah,4,5]
puts "Normal array is #{normal}"
puts "Original [] method used to get the 3rd element:"
puts normal[2]

puts '-' * 20
puts "Using the extension on the non-2D array:"
puts normal[0,1]
```

The output of this program is:

```
The 2D array is: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
Extension used on the thing to get at element 1 of first array:
2
--------------------
Normal array is [1, 2, :blah, 4, 5]
Original [] method used to get the 3rd element:
blah
--------------------
Using the extension on the non-2D array:
./test.rb:9:in `[]': Element at row 0 is not an array (ArgumentError)
    from ./test.rb:35:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Even with `prepend`, you're modifying `Array` globally. Not sure if that qualifies as "non-invasively".

Comment: Sure.  Subclass Array... and then deal with having to work with instances of your Thing instead of just using Arrays.  You could do that too.

Comment: @Stefan as opposed to reopening the class Array and redefining [] in its entirety, prepend is relatively non-invasive, which is what I was thinking when I wrote that.

Comment: Ah, I think the spirit of the question and his followup questions led me to believe that he *wanted* to change the behavior of the Array class.  He was puzzled as it why it wasn't changed....

Comment: I think the OP wanted to change the behavior of `Array#[]` within the `Thing` class only. Maybe refinements could help to achieve that (I haven't used them much).

Comment: I cannot think of a way to do that short of having the `Thing` *and* a subclass of `Array`, which would not be simple.